# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors for $\mathbf{A}$ : $\mathbb{C}^m\mapsto \mathbb{C}^n, m \neq m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wonder if matrices that maps from $\mathbb{C}^m \mapsto \mathbb{C}^n, m\neq$ n (I don not know what matrices whit this property are called) have something similar to what a matrix which maps from $\mathbb{C}^m \mapsto \mathbb{C}^n, m = n$ would call an eigenvalue and eigenvectors?

Comment: Something similar is maybe singular value decomposition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition